# Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern with sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I am experiencing the below exception if I am running the sidekiq:

It can be seen that the date_at_relative_to_now class is required twice by some weird reason despite the fact that I am not using require nor require_relative in my application. I am relying exclusively to rails autoload feature.

Any ide or help is appreciated

```
→ sidekiq
loading...
loading...
Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/concern.rb:126:in `included'
/Users/boti/Rails/checker/app/exhibits/concerns/date_at_relative_to_now.rb:6:in `<module:DateAtRelativeToNow>'
/Users/boti/Rails/checker/app/exhibits/concerns/date_at_relative_to_now.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/boti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
/Users/boti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/boti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/Users/boti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/boti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
/Users/boti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
/Users/boti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/boti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
/Users/boti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/Users/boti/Rails/checker/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/sidekiq-3.3.4/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:241:in `boot_system'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/sidekiq-3.3.4/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:50:in `run'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/gems/sidekiq-3.3.4/bin/sidekiq:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@checker/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
ruby-2.2.0@checker:boti:~/Rails/checker git:active_job_exercise 
→
```

The code for date_at_relative_to_now.rb:

```
module DateAtRelativeToNow
  puts 'loading...'
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
  end

  module ClassMethods
    attr_reader :field

    def applicable_to?(object, _context)
      field = self.field
      object.respond_to? field
    end

    def applicable_to(field)
      @field = field

      define_method field do
        date = __getobj__.send self.__class__.field
        if date.present?
          "#{distance_of_time_in_words_to_now date} ago"
        else
          'Never'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you share the code of date_at_relative_to_now.rb class?.

Answer (score 0):

Issue occuring as [activesupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f37ad331089f64ab0386e8ac94b6626b45c38a1e/activesupport/lib/active_support/concern.rb#L124) does not support include inside 'included' block.

Remove `include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper` line from DateAtRelativeToNow and included it in module or class wherever you need.

Comment: Since the class is included twice the exception is raised by the included block.

Comment: Implementation of activesupport prohibit this.

Comment: The active support is a black box. So it loads correctly, checks against double load etc... The problem could be somewhere in the code which triggers the double loading.

Answer (score 0):

Implemention of activesupport 'included' function:

```
        def included(base = nil, &block)
          if base.nil?
            raise MultipleIncludedBlocks if instance_variable_defined?(:@_included_block)

            @_included_block = block
          else
            super
          end
        end
```

Comment: I saw that code too... The main problem is that by some reason the file is loaded twice...